# Sending data from parent machine to child machine using actors

Tags: xstate

I'm trying to understand Actors to be able to pass data from a sibling component to another.

I have these machines: parent and child. `parentMachine` sends a `GET` event to `childMachine` in the `success` transition. Once `childMachine` receives an `event.value` it should be assigned to a `user` property in its context.

```
const [currentChild, sendChild] = useMachine(childMachine);
```

Now, when I log `currentChild.context` after clicking fetch, the `user` property is empty. How do I use the data received from `parentMachine` in a component that depends on `childMachine`?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-frost-9lxoh

```
const parentMachine = Machine({
  id: "parent",
  initial: "idle",
  context: {
    ref: undefined
  },
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        FETCH: {
          target: "loading"
        }
      }
    },
    loading: {
      invoke: {
        id: "getUser",
        src: (_, event) => fetchUser(event.value),
        onDone: {
          target: "success",
          actions: assign({
            user: (_, event) => {
              return event.data;
            }
          })
        },
        onError: {}
      },
      entry: assign({
        ref: () => spawn(childMachine)
      })
    },
    success: {
      entry: (ctx, evt) => ctx.ref.send({ type: "GET", value: ctx.user })
    },
    failure: {} 
  }
});
```

---

```
const childMachine = Machine(
  {
    id: "child",
    initial: "waitingForData",
    context: {
      user: []
    },
    states: {
      waitingForData: {
        on: {
          GET: {
            actions: [
              assign({
                user: (ctx, evt) => [...ctx.user, evt.value]
              }),
              "logger"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    actions: {
      logger: ctx => console.log(ctx.user)
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing that you can invoke Promises, Callbacks, Observables and Machines, as mention [here](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/communication.html#invoking-machines), when you invoke machines you have to wait until invoked machine reaches its final state, and you will receive the result in the `onDone`, and when you invoke a Promise you have to wait until it finishes and you will receive the result in the `onDone` too.

[Here you go](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-pine-lo11g?file=/src/machines.js) an example of invoking a Machine and a Promise.